# Appcelerator - QuickTime Player record - show finger tap

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, quicktime

With QuickTime player is not possibile to show the finger tap of the device that we are recording, and this is my goal.

I found [this](https://github.com/eumlab/eumtouchpointview) solution, and i wanted to know if there was something similar for the Appcelerator platform, maybe a Module (on [gitt.io](http://gitt.io/) i haven't found anything).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

whiteLine
try **Jing** to record video from mac. its comfortable and mouse cursor show in it.
i think it helps u  .

https://jing.en.softonic.com/mac